# Unable to resolve the error- TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable while using streamlit library

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, user-input, streamlit

I have been trying to create a chatbot for F1 using streamlit library. The issue I am facing is that I am continuously facing an error- TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable. I have tried exception handling but unable to identify the error. This is the code-

```
import os
import nltk
import ssl
import streamlit as st
import random
import fastf1 as ff1
import pandas as pd
st.title("F1bot")
st.write("Welcome to the F1bot. Please type a message and press Enter to ask questions related to F1.")
counter=0
counter += 1
st.write('Enter the year')
year=st.number_input("You:", key=f"user_input_{counter}")
counter+=1
st.write('Enter the venue')
venue=st.text_input("You:", key=f"user_input_{counter}")
counter+=1
st.write('Enter the race type whether it is quali or final')
rtype=st.text_input("You:", key=f"user_input_{counter}")
if rtype=='quali':
    rtype='Q'
elif rtype=='final':
    rtype='R'
quali = ff1.get_session(year,venue,rtype)
st.write("Chatbot:", value=quali.event, height=100, max_chars=None, key=f"chatbot_response_{counter}")
st.write("Thank you for chatting with me. Have a great day!")
st.stop()
```

this is the code that I have been trying and facing the error-
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable

Kindly help me out

Answer (score 0):

This is because streamlit runs all the code at once and eventually the session you create has none parameters (year, venue, rtype - empty fields).
Try putting *ff1.get_session* in if statements or maybe create predefined values for other selectors:

```
st.write("Welcome to the F1bot. Please type a message and press Enter to ask questions related to F1.")

year = st.number_input('Enter the year', step=1, value=2021)

venue = st.text_input('Enter the venue', value='Monza')

rtype=st.selectbox(
    'Race type:',
    ('Set Race Type','Qualification', 'Final'))
if rtype=='Qualification':
    quali = ff1.get_session(year, venue,"Q")
    st.write("Result:", quali.event)
if rtype=='Final':
    quali = ff1.get_session(year, venue, "R")
    st.write("Result:", quali.event)
```

Comment: Actually I want to take input for year, venue and race type from the user through the interface. How to go about it? If you can help me in providing the solution.

Comment: You can just remove the "value='Monza'" and the code will work as you expect. The main thing is to set the request to the ff1 in the last if statement

Comment: I added the request in the last if statement but still the same error is coming.

Comment: year=st.number_input("You:", key=f"user_input_{counter}")
st.write(year)
counter+=1
venue=st.text_input("You:", key=f"user_input_{counter}")
st.write(venue)
counter+=1
rtype=st.text_input("You:", key=f"user_input_{counter}")
st.write(rtype)
quali = ff1.get_session(year,venue,rtype)
if quali is not None:
    st.write("Chatbot:", value=quali.event, height=100, max_chars=None, key=f"chatbot_response_{counter}")
st.write("Chatbot:",quali.event)
st.write("Thank you for chatting with me. Have a great day!")

Comment: Try the code I've pinned in my answer, because besides, you did not added the request in if and the year value in your code returns a float, not an int as required by the API